# Calculate with .val() of input jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm working on a project, and i have to make some calculations on an existing value of an input field. let's say the input value is 400 or whatever.

underneath i've got a select box **YES** means add **425**, **NO** means add **0** or substract -425;

HTML:

```
<input id="priceTag" name="priceTag" type="text" value="400">

<select id="designChoice" name="designChoice">
     <option>Choose--</option>
     <option value="yes">yes</option>
     <option value="no">no</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var priceTag = $('#priceTag');        

    $('#designChoice').on('change', function(){

        if($(this).val()==='yes'){              
          /* Here i want to add + 425 to the */

        }else{
          /* Here I want to add nothing to the input or substract -425 */   
        }

    });
});
```

What i've tried:

```
priceTag.val(+ 425);
/* And more of this type of wrong code ;-P */
```

I've tried to look up existing examples but i didn't find many examples so thanks in advance for the answer!

Comment: You're tottaly right i wil edit my post, thanks!

Comment: In which case of "no" do you subtract 425 and in which do you leave the value untouched? That's an important point, otherwise your question cannot be answered properly.

Comment: He means 425 should be subtracted when clicking `no` if it has already been added by clicking `yes`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The logic to this is a little more complicated. You need to know if `425` has already been added before `no` has been clicked, in which case you need to subtract `425`, not just add `0`.

With that in mind you could add a `data` attribute to the input to contain it's starting price:

```
<input id="priceTag" name="priceTag" type="text" value="400" data-default="400">
```

Then when the `select` is changed you can convert the data attribute to an integer and then perform the calculation on it. Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var $priceTag = $('#priceTag');        
    $('#designChoice').on('change', function () {
        if ($(this).val() === 'yes') {
            $priceTag.val(parseInt($priceTag.data('default'), 10) + 425);            
        } else {
            $priceTag.val($priceTag.data('default'));
        }        
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ea896vfq/)

Comment: why do you use the functions (with useless parameters) inside the val?

Comment: @Christoph good point. I was originally going to amend the current value, which the function is useful for. However with already having a reference to the `priceTag` element the functions are not needed.

Comment: Very clever to just use the data-default never thought about that

Comment: Well, I guess that's a matter of taste. I dislike this notation. I would find it more convenient to retrieve `parseInt(priceTag.data('default'),10)` once and store it in a variable. Having unnecessary functions with unused parameters is not very nice style imo.

Comment: @Paul This does not work if you change the value... it will always be 400, which I don't think you want...

Comment: Also I guess your code is missing the `-425` part... ;)

Comment: @Christoph no, my code doesn't need it as it simply resets the value to the default.

Comment: I am saying this is a good answer if the input value is never manually changed by the user, otherwise this is not an answer at all.  So just making sure he knows that.

Comment: @true, I overlooked this;) Looks fine but only as long as the input field is unchanged. You are better of checking `val()` directly and store the decision whether the "425" has been added in a separate field rather then using a "default" field.

Comment: @SimplyCraig That's true. I'll amend if OP requires it.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var priceTag = $('#priceTag');        
    var selectedYes=false;
    $('#designChoice').on('change', function(){
        if($(this).val()==='yes'){              
          /* Here i want to add + 425 to the */
            selectedYes=true;
            priceTag.val( ( +priceTag.val() ) + 425 );
        }else if (selectedYes){
          /* Here I want to add nothing to the input */ 
            priceTag.val( ( +priceTag.val() ) - 425 );
            selectedYes=false;
        }

    });
});
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/0xvkupe2/1/

Comment: If you keep selecting yes/no/yes/no, the price isn't reset and instead increments by 425 each time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer this was working. Indeed it has to substract if no is selected

Comment: @Paul Updated answer and JsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

Save the value of `#priceTag` to a data attribute on page load and whenever the user changes it:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var priceTag = $('#priceTag'),
        designChoice = $('#designChoice');
    
    //save initial value and whenever it is changed to a data attribute
    priceTag.on('change', function() {
        $(this).data('value', this.value);
        designChoice.change();
    })
    .change();

    designChoice.on('change', function(){

        if($(this).val()==='yes') {
            /* Here i want to add + 425 to the */
            priceTag.val( +priceTag.data('value') + 425 );
        } else{
            /* Here I want to add nothing to the input or substract -425 */ 
            priceTag.val( priceTag.data('value') );
        }

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="priceTag" name="priceTag" type="text" value="400">

<select id="designChoice" name="designChoice">
     <option>Choose--</option>
     <option value="yes">yes</option>
     <option value="no">no</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is.

jQuery:

```
var priceTagAns = 0;   
$(document).ready(function(){   

    $('#designChoice').on('change', function(){

        if($(this).val()==='yes'){              
          /* Here i want to add + 425 to the */
           priceTagAns = (Number($("#priceTag").val()) + 425);
        }else{
          /* Here I want to add nothing to the input */ 
            priceTagAns = (Number($("#priceTag").val()));
        }
        alert(priceTagAns);
    });

});
```

The Alert is just to prove the value is set, do with it what you want.

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/89z7qpkf/2/

*** UPDATED ***

Also Variable version: http://jsfiddle.net/89z7qpkf/3/

Comment: If you keep selecting yes/no/yes/no, the price isn't reset and instead increments by 425 each time.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan However it changes the `input` so I don't see any issue with this, however you could always have a hidden `input` that just stores this value so you never touch the actual `input` used.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan fixed for what you want with hidden input. or you could use a variable as well to store the answer